# Regex pattern to extract substring

Tags: python, regex, string

mystring  = `"q1)whatq2)whenq3)where"`

want something like `["q1)what", "q2)when", "q3)where"]`

My approach is to find the `q\d+\)` pattern then move till I find this pattern again and stop. But I'm not able to stop.

I did `req_list =  re.compile("q\d+\)[*]\q\d+\)").split(mystring)`

But this gives the whole string. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code which uses `re.findall` function,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "q1)whatq2)whenq3)where"
>>> m = re.findall(r'q\d+\)(?:(?!q\d+).)*', s)
>>> m
['q1)what', 'q2)when', 'q3)where']
```

**Explanation:**

- `q\d+\)` Matches the string in the format `q` followed by one or more digits and again followed by `)` symbol.
- `(?:(?!q\d+).)*` Negative look-ahead which matches any char not of `q\d+` zero or more times.